# Google Sheets - Query and Importrange from many files

Tags: database, google-sheets, importrange

I´m using Google Drive Sheets for colection data from many users - there is about fifty files with same structure. That files are "alive" but I need analyse them by filters all together etc.

```
=QUERY(
{
IMPORTRANGE("xxxx";"JedenKlient!A3:N");
IMPORTRANGE("yyyy";"JedenKlient!A3:N");
...
IMPORTRANGE("zzz";"JedenKlient!A3:N")
};"where Col1 is not null")
```

When I use this QUERY and IMPORTRANGE with 2 files - its working well. After I put there more files - Google Sheets send me back error "in ARRAY_LITERAL - missing values". I found somethings "about different numbers of columns" but my files have the same structure - of course - different numbers of rows...

Can you please help me fix this issue?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried waiting? Or Have you tried 3 to 4 IMPORTRANGES simultaneously?

Comment: From my experience, this error always indicates missing column.  1. Check for sure whether all imported range has the same number of columns. 2. Sometimes you have to wait, as my predecessor stated, for several seconds (especially when adding new importranges). 3. Try adding one by one and then you will be able to pinpoint problematic external sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - I must put every IMPORTRANGE to cell and click on popup button. This need to be done file by file. Unfortunately.

After that whole query start working.